# UPDATE to database using PDO error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i used PDO to update my values to table using following method

**form**

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="submitupdate.php" autocomplete="off">
   <input class="update" type="text" name="fullname"></li>
   <input class="update" type="text" name="dob"></li>
   <textarea style="width:740px;height:220px;" class="update" type="text" name="intrested"></textarea></li>
   <textarea style="width:740px;height:220px;" class="update" type="text" name="description"></textarea></li>
</form>
```

**Processing**

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php');
//if not logged in redirect to login page
if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';
//include header template
?>
<?php

    try {

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $intrested = $_POST['intrested'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `members`   
   SET `fullname` = :firstname,
       `dob` = :dob,
       `intrested` = :intrested,
       `description` = :description 
 WHERE `username` = :username";



    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(":username", $username);
    $statement->bindValue(":fullname", $fullname);
    $statement->bindValue(":dob", $dob);
    $statement->bindValue(":intrested", $intrested);
    $statement->bindValue(":description", $description);
    $count = $statement->execute();

    $db = null;        // Disconnect
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Am updating column using user name **not** by `ID` i updat happen using `username` and user name is called using session

i get following error

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

can someone help me

Comment: If you have edited the question to fix the original problem you should ask a new question. Please close this question and ask it again because the answers below are no longer applicable to what you are asking and I am confused what your actual question is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the query before you are setting the values. At the time of execution of the query, the values you are trying to use are not set yet, so there is not any data to replace the placeholders.

This should work:

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php');
//if not logged in redirect to login page
if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';
//include header template

try {

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $intrested = $_POST['intrested'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `members`   
   SET `fullname` = :fullname,
       `dob` = :dob,
       `inserted` = :inserted,
       `description` = :description 
 WHERE `username` = :username";



    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $params = array(
        ":username" => $username,
        ":fullname" => $fullname,
        ":dob" => $dob,
        ":inserted" => $intrested,
        ":description" => $description
    );
    $count = $statement->execute($params);

    $conn = null;        // Disconnect
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: i get `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined` made some edit check my question

Answer (score 1):

Does code is completed?

I see $row but where you defined $row ?

BTW you are executing a query before setting the values ​​to use.

replace your code with this:

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php');
//if not logged in redirect to login page
if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';
//include header template

try {



    $sql = "UPDATE `members`   
   SET `fullname` = :firstname,
       `dob` = :dob,
       `inserted` = :inserted,
       `description` = :description 
 WHERE `username` = :username";


    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    $dob = $row['dob'];
    $intrested = $row['intrested'];
    $description = $row['description'];    


    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(":username", $username);
    $statement->bindValue(":fullname", $fullname);
    $statement->bindValue(":dob", $dob);
    $statement->bindValue(":inserted", $intrested);
    $statement->bindValue(":description", $description);
    $count = $statement->execute();

    $conn = null;        // Disconnect
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: i get `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined` made some edit check my question

Comment: there wer some mistake check my question made some edit